# Positioning a custom UILabel inside a UITableView footer view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController and I am setting the footerView via

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = FooterView()
```

In the class FooterView I have added a label via

```
self.addSubView(label)
```

I noticed the following.

- The footerView is positioning on top of the tableView
- The label is inside the footerview

My questions are

- When I set the Frame of the footerView as (0, 0, 100, 100) it seems to be overlapping on the tableView. How do I position the footer at the bottom of the tableView ?
- When a label is added via addSubView() of the footer. Is it positioning related to the footerView or the tableView?

Answer (score 1):

- FooterView's default height is 44.If you don't set your footerView's height for more and then set your label with height of 100 then it overlaps.
- It is positioning with the footerView.

You can set the footerView's height by using UITableViewDelegate method.Below is the way to achieve what you wanted.Footer view only at the bottom of table view.

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView .dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellIdentifier") as! UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = "trial"
        return cell
    }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    if section == 1{
        return 100
    }
        return 0

}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2 //The number you needed + 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    if section == 1{

        return FooterView()
    }
    return nil
}
```

Delete this line

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = FooterView()
```

Comment: Thanks, how do I not set the height ? Doesn't the CGRect need all 4 parameters when I create the view ?

Comment: That would be a footer for a particular section right ? I meant a footer for the entire tableView.

Comment: @PrakashRaman In the last edit, there is a footer for the entire tableView.Check this

Comment: Ah, I see what you are saying. So I just have a footer for the last section in my TableView right ? Yes, that would make sense thanks :)
Although, I would want to see how I could use tableView.tableFooterView

Comment: Yes, that's right. In which specific case do you want to see how you could use tableView.tableFooterView? If you can tell the difference which we are expecting to occur, I can help you further. @PrakashRaman

Comment: Thanks @pandaren-codemaster although, it was more from an educational point of view.